# How can I round an evalue in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval, rounding

I have an evalue number like: `3,49489484848484E-23` and want to round it to 
`3,48E-23`

How can I do it? I can't found any Perl functions that do this rounding.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) or [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html):

```
printf '%.2e', 3.49489484848484E-23; # prints 3.49e-23
```

See also the [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Does-Perl-have-a-round%28%29-function?-What-about-ceil%28%29-and-floor%28%29?-Trig-functions?).

Comment: @Angelo you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the answer that has helped you the most.

Answer (score 6):

Perl doesn't have a `round()` function. Treating floats is always system-dependent, etc. 
From the [Perl FAQ](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#Does-Perl-have-a-round-function-What-about-ceil-and-floor-Trig-functions-) I can offer you this:

> For rounding to a certain number of digits, sprintf() or printf() is
>   usually the easiest route.
>
> [...]
>
> Rounding in financial applications can have serious implications, and
>   the rounding method used should be specified precisely. In these
>   cases, it probably pays not to trust whichever system of rounding is
>   being used by Perl, but instead to implement the rounding function you
>   need yourself.